# why am i getting .UnauthorizedAccessException?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, backgroundworker

I am trying to retrieve images from media library to a warp panel inside listbox 'lstImageFromMediaLibrary', also am trying that while the images load i show a loading screen using a usercontrol and adding it to popup.child
but i am getting this exceeption 'UnauthorizedAccessException'
when i remove all backgrougWorker related code no such unauthorized access is there....

```
     void backroungWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
      {

        foreach (Picture p in mediaLibrary.Pictures)
        {

            bitmapImage.SetSource(p.GetThumbnail());
            lstBitmapImage.Add(bitmapImage);
        }


        this.lstImageFromMediaLibrary.ItemsSource = lstBitmapImage;
    }
```

any help is appriciated , i hope i made myself clear....

EDIT:
ok so now m doing this

```
    BackgroundWorker backroungWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    Popup popup = new Popup();
    public PanoramaPage1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        showpopup();
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        backroungWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backroungWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backroungWorker_DoWork);
        backroungWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backroungWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        backroungWorker.ProgressChanged+=new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backroungWorker_ProgressChanged);
        backroungWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
     void backroungWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            popup.IsOpen = false;
        }
        );
    }
     void backroungWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
     {
         backroungWorker.ReportProgress(10);

     }
     void backroungWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
     {
         this.InitializePage();
     }


    private void showpopup()
    {

        popup.Child = new SplashScreenControl();
        popup.Width = 480;
        popup.IsOpen = true;

    }

    private void InitializePage()
    {

        MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
        List<BitmapImage> lstBitmapImage = new List<BitmapImage>();
        foreach (Picture p in mediaLibrary.Pictures)
        {
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.SetSource(p.GetThumbnail());
            lstBitmapImage.Add(bitmapImage);
        }


        this.lstImageFromMediaLibrary.ItemsSource = lstBitmapImage;
    }
```

but still the progress bar just shows a dot and nothing else.....

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing your User Interface in your [DoWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx) Event. You should be communicating to your application through the Background Worker Events such as the [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) or the [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) Events.

From First link:

> You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in your DoWork event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface through the BackgroundWorker events.

Comment: @aadilsiddiqui In looking at the code that you added, you are doing your work in the ProgressChanged Event which is on the same thread as your application, you are not getting any benifits from your backgroundworker. What you need to do is **Do all** of your work in your `DoWork` Event then assign your lstBitmapImage to the `e.Result` of `DoWork` it will be available in the `RunWorkerCompleted` Events e.Result in a Usuable form. You would then use the ProgressChanged Event to increment your Progress Bar depending on how much of your media library you have processed.